# Recovering fractional ideals from ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain; let ${I_{(i)}}$ be a set of fractional ideals in $K$, the fraction field of $R$, indexed by a lattice such that $I_{(i)} I_{(j)} = I_{(i + j)}$. Let $J_{(i)} = I_{(i)} \cap R$.

Is it possible to recover $I_{(i)}$ from knowing all the $J_{(i)}$?

Comment: What are the restrictions on your indexing set?  What do you mean by a "lattice" in this context?

Comment: Lattice here would just mean a finite dimensional free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^n$. It does have to be the full lattice (and not a subcone), as otherwise you could pick fractional ideals including $R$.